# Is a function that preserves the cross product necessarily linear in $\mathbb R^3$? $f(a) \times f(b) = a \times b$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-equations, cross-product

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ is a function such that
$$
f(a) \times f(b)=a \times b
$$
for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R^3}$, where ''$\times$'' denotes the cross product in $\mathbb{R^3}$.
Does $f$ have to be a linear mapping?

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Note: As $f$ is linear (see answer from servaes) we can set $f(a)=Ca$ with a $3\times 3$-matrix $C.$ Then $f(a)\times f(b)=a\times b$ becomes $\mathrm{adj}(C)=I.$ This means $C=I$ or $C=-I$, which in turn means $f(a)=a\forall a\in\mathbb{R}^3$ or $f(a)=-a\forall a\in\mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: @ReinhardMeier seems $f$ could be multiplication by any scalar.

Comment: @hunter If $f$ is multiplication by a scalar $\lambda$, then $(\lambda a) \times (\lambda b) = a \times b$ for all $a, b \implies \lambda^2 = 1$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286683/maps-of-mathbbr3-commuting-with-the-cross-product for the related question of maps satisfying $f(a) \times f(b) = f(a \times b)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, but only in the trivial sense that the *only* functions $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ that preserve the cross product in the sense used in your question (i.e. $f(a) \times f(b) = a \times b$) are the identity function $f(x) = x$ and the reflection $f(x) = -x$, which of course are indeed both linear.

This can be seen with a simple geometric argument.  First, note that if $a$ and $b$ are any two non-collinear vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, then $a \times b$ is orthogonal to the unique plane containing $a$, $b$ and the origin, and that the vectors in this plane are the only ones orthogonal to $a \times b$.  Thus $f(a) \times f(b) = a \times b$ implies that both $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ must also belong to the same plane passing through the origin as $a$ and $b$, and thus planes passing through the origin must be an invariant set of $f$.

But since any line through the origin is the intersection of two planes through the origin, and since the intersection of two invariant sets is itself an invariant set, each line through the origin must also be an invariant set of $f$.  This implies that $f(x)$ must be collinear with $x$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^3$, i.e. that $f(x) = s(x) x$ for some scaling function $s: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$, and thus that $f(a) \times f(b) = s(a) a \times s(b) b$.

All that remains to be shown is that this scaling function $s$ must in fact be constant over $\mathbb R^3$ (at least excluding the origin) and equal to $\pm 1$.  We can do this using the bilinearity of the cross product, which implies that $f(a) \times f(b) = s(a) a \times s(b) b = s(a) s(b) (a \times b)$.  If $a$ and $b$ are not collinear, then $a \times b \ne 0$, and thus $$f(a) \times f(b) = s(a) s(b) (a \times b) = a \times b \implies s(a) s(b) = 1.$$  Now, let $a$ and $b$ be any two (non-zero) vectors, and let $c$ not be collinear with either of them.  Then $s(a)s(c) = s(b)s(c) = 1$, implying that $s(a) = s(b)$, and thus that $s$ is constant over $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$.

Finally, we merely need to note that the only constant solutions to $s^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb R$ are $s = 1$ and $s = -1$, yielding only two possible functions $f$: either $f(x) = x$ or $f(x) = -x$.  And, as $(-a) \times (-b) = a \times b$, both of these do indeed satisfy the original criterion.

Comment: Arbitrary rotations in $R^3$ also preserves the cross product in the sense used in question

Comment: @Alex: No they don't. Rotations "preserve the cross product" in the sense that $f(a) \times f(b) = f(a \times b)$, but that's not what your question asks for.

Comment: For example, let $x$, $y$ and $z$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^3$ such that $x \times y = z$, and let $f$ be a 90° rotation around the $x$ axis such that $f(x) = x$ and $f(y) = z$. Then $f(x) \times f(y) = x \times z = -y \ne x \times y$ (but $-y = f(x \times y)$).

Comment: You have right. I confused the two equations.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen re your second to last paragraph: is it possible that there can be pathological $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $s(c) = 0$ for all $c$ in the orthogonal space to $\langle a, b \rangle$? If so, I don’t think you can immediately conclude $s(a) = s(b)$.

Comment: @SamFreedman: No, because then $s(a)s(c)$ and $s(b)s(c)$ would be $0$, not $1$. :)

Answer (score 25):

Yes, $f$ is necessarily linear.

Note that the image of $f$ must contain a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, otherwise it is contained in a two-dimensional subspace, say, $\{v\}^\perp$ for some nonzero vector $v$, but this is a contradiction because $f(a)\times f(b)$ always lies inside $\operatorname{span}\{v\}$, while the set of all cross products $a\times b$ is $\mathbb R^3$.

Now pick any two vectors $a,b$ and any scalar $\lambda$. For any vector $c$, we have
\begin{aligned}
f(\lambda a+b)\times f(c)
&=(\lambda a+b)\times c\\
&=\lambda(a\times c)+b\times c\\
&=\lambda\left(f(a)\times f(c)\right)+f(b)\times f(c)\\
&=\left(\lambda f(a)+f(b)\right)\times f(c).
\end{aligned}
By our previous argument, when $c$ runs through $\mathbb R^3$, its image $f(c)$ will run through at least a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.
Hence the above equalities imply that $f(\lambda a+b)=\lambda f(a)+f(b)$. Since $a,b$ and $\lambda$ are arbitrary, $f$ is linear.

Comment: +1, the first paragraph needs the additional hypothesis that $f$ is not the zero map.

Comment: @hunter I don't see why. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: The zero map preserves cross products but its image does not contain a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @user1551 Oh sorry, you're right. I thought the question was about perserving the cross products in the sense of $f(a)\times f(b) = f(a\times b)$.

Comment: @user1551 yes, I made the same mistake

Answer (score 12):

First note that $f$ is injective; if $f(x)=f(x')$ for some $x,x'\in\Bbb{R}^3$ then for all $y\in\Bbb{R}^3$ we have
$$x\times y=f(x)\times f(y)=f(x')\times f(y)=x'\times y,$$
and hence $(x-x')\times y=0$ for all $y\in\Bbb{R}^3$, which shows that $x=x'$.

Next we want to show $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}^3$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$. Note that
$$
f(x)\times f(\lambda x)=x\times(\lambda x)=\lambda(x\times x)=0
$$
for all all $x\in\Bbb{R}^3$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$. Because $f(x) \neq 0$ if $x \neq 0$, for nonzero $x$ we have $f(\lambda x)=\mu f(x)$ for some $\mu\in\Bbb{R}$, where $\mu$ may depend on $\lambda$ and $x$. In order to prove $\mu = \lambda$, for all $y\in\Bbb{R}^3$
$$
(\lambda x)\times y=f(\lambda x)\times f( y)=(\mu f(x))\times f(y)=\mu(f(x)\times f(y))=\mu(x\times y) = (\mu x) \times y,
$$
so $((\lambda - \mu)x) \times y = 0$. Therefore $(\lambda - \mu)x = 0$, so $\mu=\lambda$ since $x \not= 0$. Thus $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ for all  all $x\in\Bbb{R}^3$ and all $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$.

Finally, note that for all nonzero $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^3$ we have $f(y)\neq0$ and so from
$$f(x+y)\times f(y)=(x+y)\times y=(x\times y)+(y\times y)=x\times y=f(x)\times f(y),$$
it follows that $f(x+y)-f(x)=\lambda f(y)$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$. Similarly we have
$$f(x+y)\times f(x)=f(y)\times f(x),$$
which shows that $f(x+y)-f(y)=\mu f(x)$ for some $\mu\in\Bbb{R}$. It follows that
$$f(x)+\lambda f(y)=f(x+y)=\mu f(x)+f(y),$$
and hence that $f((1-\mu)x)=f((1-\lambda)y)$. As $f$ is injective this implies $(1-\mu)x=(1-\lambda)y$, so if $x$ and $y$ are noncollinear this shows that $\lambda=\mu=1$ and hence that
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y).$$
Of course if $x$ and $y$ are collinear, say $y=\lambda x$, then we already saw that
$$f(x+y)=f(x+\lambda x)=(1+\lambda)f(x)=f(x)+\lambda f(x)=f(x)+f(y).$$
This shows that $f$ is indeed linear, so the hypothesis is redundant.

Comment: Your argument that $\mu = \lambda$ has some gaps. That $f(\lambda x)$ is a scalar multiple of $f(x)$ would be invalid if $f(x) = \mathbf 0$.  Why is $f(x) \not= \mathbf 0$? And $\mu$ initially may depend on $\lambda$ and $x$, but you don't indicate that anywhere.  That means proving $\mu = \lambda$ needs more care.  Say $(\lambda x) \times y = (\mu x) \times y$ for all $y$, so $((\lambda - \mu)x)) \times y = \mathbf 0$ for all $y$. Letting $y$ run through the standard unit vectors shows $(\lambda - \mu)x = \mathbf 0$.  If $x \not= \mathbf 0$ then $\mu = \lambda$.  But if $x = \mathbf 0\ldots$

Comment: @KCd Good points. Indeed $\mu$ may depend on $\lambda$ and $x$. The next line immediately shows that $\mu=\lambda$ for that particular $\lambda$ and $x$, and this entire first argument holds for all $\lambda$ and $x$. I'll see if I can make that clearer.

Comment: As for why $f(x)\neq0$; I should have taken more care when reordering the steps in my proof. I later show that $f$ is injective, in an earlier version I showed this at the start. I'll rearrange a bit.

Comment: @KCd I have updated my answer, hopefully there are no more gaps now.

Comment: You forgot to show early on that $f(\mathbf 0) = \mathbf 0$, since that is why $f(x) \not= \mathbf 0$ when $x \not= \mathbf 0$.

Comment: Is it true that $f(0)=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why Servaes is not returning to fill in that gap.  The way I worked it out is a bit tricky.